# issue with spring hibernate jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am having issue with my jpa implementation in springboot. I really don't know where to place my hand in resolving the error. Here is the error I am getting:

```
 Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRestController' defined in file [C:\Users\Iredafe\eclipse-workspace\logger-app-jpa\target\classes\com\dafe\spring\logger\rest\EmployeeRestController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Iredafe\eclipse-workspace\logger-app-jpa\target\classes\com\dafe\spring\logger\service\EmployeeServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dafe.spring.logger.dao.EmployeeDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=employeeDAOJpaImpl)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1340) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at com.dafe.spring.logger.LoggerApplication.main(LoggerApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Iredafe\eclipse-workspace\logger-app-jpa\target\classes\com\dafe\spring\logger\service\EmployeeServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dafe.spring.logger.dao.EmployeeDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=employeeDAOJpaImpl)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1340) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1255) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dafe.spring.logger.dao.EmployeeDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=employeeDAOJpaImpl)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1662) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1221) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

I don't understand what is error log means: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dafe.spring.logger.dao.EmployeeDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=employeeDAOJpaImpl)}.

check out my service implementation class known as EmployeeServiceImpl

```
package com.dafe.spring.logger.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.dafe.spring.logger.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.dafe.spring.logger.entity.Employee;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeServiceImpl(@Qualifier("employeeDAOJpaImpl") EmployeeDAO theEmployeeDAO) {
        employeeDAO = theEmployeeDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        return employeeDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Employee findById(int theId) {
        return employeeDAO.findById(theId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Employee theEmployee) {
        employeeDAO.save(theEmployee);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteById(int theId) {
        employeeDAO.deleteById(theId);
    }

}
```

check out my DAO Jpa implementation class:

```
package com.dafe.spring.logger.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.dafe.spring.logger.entity.Employee;

public class EmployeeDAOJpaImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeDAOJpaImpl(EntityManager theEntityManager) {
        entityManager = theEntityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findAll() {

        //create a query
                Query theQuery =
                            entityManager.createQuery("from Employee");

        //execute query and get result list
        List<Employee> employees = theQuery.getResultList();

        //return the results


        return employees;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee findById(int theId) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Employee theEmployee) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int theId) {

    }

}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put **@Repository** annotation to make dao class as spring bean.

```
package com.dafe.spring.logger.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.dafe.spring.logger.entity.Employee;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOJpaImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeDAOJpaImpl(EntityManager theEntityManager) {
        entityManager = theEntityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findAll() {

        //create a query
                Query theQuery =
                            entityManager.createQuery("from Employee");

        //execute query and get result list
        List<Employee> employees = theQuery.getResultList();

        //return the results


        return employees;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee findById(int theId) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Employee theEmployee) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int theId) {

    }

}
```